# Disable paste action if the value contains a specific string

Tags: jquery

I have textarea. How can I prevent the user pasting text in to it if the text contains the sub string: `data:image`, or `src="data:image`, or `base64`?

```
<textarea id="editor-area" name="msgText" class="form-control" rows="9"><?PHP echo nl2br ($_POST['msgText']) ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Create a `paste` handler. Check the value with a regular expression, and call `event.preventDefault()` if it matches.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @Barmar we need a macro to add that as a comment :)

Comment: @giorgiga I use the AutoReviewComments extension.

Comment: @Barmar Whoa, nice!  I never knew about this.  https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se